# Simple QuickCheck Test Never Completes

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my mind around QuickCheck. Consider the following simple data type and it's corresponding arbitrary instance.

EDIT: Full code below as requested in a comment. `fixedToFractional` converts fixed numeric types such as `Micro` to `Fractional`.

```
import Data.Fixed
import System.Random
import Control.Applicative
import Test.QuickCheck

fixedToFractional :: (HasResolution a, Fractional b) => Data.Fixed.Fixed a -> b
fixedToFractional = fromRational . toRational

instance Random Micro where
    randomR (lo, hi) g = randomR (fixedToFractional lo, fixedToFractional hi) g
    random g           = randomR (-999999, 999999) g

data FooType = FooType { foo :: Micro } deriving (Show)

instance Arbitrary FooType where
    arbitrary =
        FooType <$> x
        where
            x = choose (0.0, 1.0)
```

If I understand things correctly, this should allow random `FooType` values to be generated, with the `foo` field set to a random value between 0 and 1.

Next, consider the following simple test.

```
prop_foo_is_gte_zero ft = (foo ft) >= 0.0
```

When I attempt to run the above test, whether in ghci, or in a test file using `quickCheckAll`, the test never completes. `ghc` eats up a few gigs of RAM in a matter of seconds, and will eventually run my machine out of swap space if I don't kill it. I'm probably missing something incredibly fundamental/stupid, but (obviously) don't know what. Any ideas?

EDIT: I am now questioning my `Random` instance. Perhaps the problem is there and not with my `Arbitrary` instance.

Comment: can you give the complete code (including `imports`)?  Because just your code will not compile with the obvious imports - [`choose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#v:choose) will want `Micro` to be an instance of `Random`

Comment: @CarstenKönig I have edited the question to include the full code. Sorry about that. In the process, you have caused me to question my `Random` instance... My thought was to convert the input to `Fractional` values and then call the `Fractional` instance of `randomR`, but I may have inadvertently created an infinitely recursing function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have an issue inside your `Random` instance for `Micro`

Here is a quick hack to fix it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Fixed
import System.Random
import Test.QuickCheck

toDouble :: Micro -> Double
toDouble = realToFrac . toRational

instance Random Micro where
    randomR (lo, hi) g =
      let (a,g') = randomR (toDouble lo, toDouble hi) g
      in (fromRational (toRational a), g')
    random = randomR (-999999, 999999)

data FooType = FooType { foo :: Micro } deriving (Show)

instance Arbitrary FooType where
    arbitrary =
        FooType <$> x
        where
            x = choose (0.0, 1.0)

main :: IO ()
main = quickCheck prop_foo_is_gte_zero
  where prop_foo_is_gte_zero ft = foo ft >= 0.0
```